# Error while connecting to redis from C# on Windows using StackExchange library

Tags: c#, windows, redis

I'm trying to connect to Redis on Windows in C# using [StackExchange library](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) but got error:

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: No connection is
>   available to service this operation: HMSET user:user1; SocketFailure
>   on localhost:6379/Subscription, origin: Error, input-buffer: 0,
>   outstanding: 0, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago,
>   unanswered-write: 7979s ago, keep-alive: 60s, pending: 0, state:
>   Connecting, last-heartbeat: never, last-mbeat: -1s ago, global: 1s ago

my code look like this:

```
class RedisConnectionFactory
{
    private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> Connection;

    private static Lazy<ConfigurationOptions> configurationOptions = new Lazy<ConfigurationOptions>(() =>
    {
        var configurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions();
        configurationOptions.EndPoints.Add("127.0.0.1", 6379);
        configurationOptions.Password = "<PASS>";
        configurationOptions.ClientName = "JakubStompor";
        configurationOptions.AbortOnConnectFail = false;
        configurationOptions.Ssl = false;
        configurationOptions.ConnectTimeout = 1000;
        configurationOptions.SyncTimeout = 3000;
        return configurationOptions;
    });

    static RedisConnectionFactory()
    {
        Connection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(
            () => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configurationOptions.Value)
        );
    }
    public static ConnectionMultiplexer GetConnection() => Connection.Value;
}

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var conn = RedisConnectionFactory.GetConnection();
        IDatabase db = conn.GetDatabase();
        db.HashSet("user:user1", new HashEntry[] { new HashEntry("12", "13"), new HashEntry("14", "15") });
    }
}
```

I've run the redis server and I can connect using command line.

Answer (score 0):

Could your ConnectTimeout be too low? Can you try increasing this to 5000 or more to see if it helps?

configurationOptions.ConnectTimeout = 1000;

Comment: Hi Carl, i make it in different way. I created a VM with linux and I connect to that machine via Ngrok. Now everything works fine. Thanks for Your response :)